# What is the endpoint for an Azure SQL database for using in a REST get request?

Tags: azure-sql-database, connections

I am new to Azure SQL database and was hoping that I would get some help on how to address the database as an endpoint in a http request I am doing from an apex callout in Salesforce.

Normally in callout we use this code snippet. So my issue is I only have the IP address of the SQL database eg. 1.2.3.4. What will my endpoint look like?

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
          HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
          Http http = new Http();
                   
          endpoint = 'https://my_endpoint.example.com/some_path';
 
          req.setHeader('Authorization', header);
          req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
          req.setMethod('POST');
          req.setBody('Information you wanna send');
          res = http.send(req);
          String sJson = res.getBody();
          System.debug('Str:' + res.getBody());
          }
          catch (Exception e) {         
            System.debug('Error:' + e.getMessage() + 'Line no:' + e.getLineNumber() );           
          }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are some api for Azure Sql Database (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/) but their purpose is to manage the database.

Comment: I want to do a daily sync of SQL db with Salesforce. The client does not want to use the paid azure pipelines so I want to write a class that updates Salesforce on a daily basis with changes in azure sql db.

Comment: So you have to build your own methods implementing r/w operations by quering every table you need.